# Adding y values to a plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I would like to add the y values to my plot for each year to make the graph easily readable but not sure how to do it. I have tried using the enumerate function but it does not return the desired output. Any guidance on this would be helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

laikipia = pd.DataFrame({
    "2020":[5.21, 20.91, 17.05],
    "2021":[20.91, 19.91, 19.76],
    }, 
    index=["Cropland", "Forestland", "Shrubland"]
)
c = ['#FFDB5C', '#358221', '#EECFA8']

laikipia.plot(kind="bar", color=c)
plt.title("")
plt.xlabel("Laikipia LULC")
plt.ylabel("Area Loss (ha)")
plt.legend(laikipia, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
#plt.yticks(round [plotdata], 0)

x = laikipia

y = [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]

max_y_lim = max(y) 
min_y_lim = min(y)
plt.ylim(min_y_lim, max_y_lim)


for i, v in enumerate(y):
    plt.text(0, i, y[i], str(v), ha="center", va = "bottom") 
         
plt.show()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBKv6.jpg)

Comment: use [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html): `ax = laikipia.plot.bar(color=c); ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])`

Comment: @tdy thanks a lot it works perfectly!